# Ubuntu vs Windows : Virus definition

Tags: 12.04, windows, windows-xp

**Does Ubuntu gets a virus??**
i think it doesn't but then if it doesn't then why so??
what separates Ubuntu and Windows that *viruses* can not be defined for Ubuntu??

Comment: What's possible and what's seen often enough to be of note are two different things.  There are virii for Linux (most if not all of which can operate in Ubuntu systems), but effectively all of them are aimed at servers, where there might be information worth stealing or a service to be denied.  A virus on a desktop/laptop system is very rarely seen "in the wild" on Linux of any flavor, but that doesn't mean it's impossible; there's nothing inherent in Linux that prevents worms, Trojans, or other malware, either (though standard security makes it harder for them to install than on Windows).

Answer (score 5):

Up till today Ubuntu (or better: Linux) can get a virus in theory. There are some ways to get a virus but up to now they need your co-operation. You need to download the virus from somewhere suspicious (we Ubuntu users 9 out of 10 times use the safe Ubuntu Software Center making us a harder target). You need to activate the virus by running the code that holds the virus.

Some might say that the amount of users play a big part in why Windows is targeted more by virus. I doubt that for 1 reason: IF someone can break Linux with a virus that could spread itself over other Linux systems they would become infamous. And pride is a big part for the hackers that matter (not the script kids that copy/paste code and change 1 line of code).

Windows is and has been broken from the start so it is an easy target. Microsoft would have done a so much better operating system if they enforced an admin account and sandboxed the users account. Got a virus? Delete the user acccount and their infected files but the system itself would remain safe.

Comment: The amount of home users does not really matter: Servers are more interesting and a lot (if not more) servers run Linux. Furthermore, there are about 2 Windows Supercomputers among the TOP500 (and they are far from top), the others run mostly Linux (http://www.top500.org/statistics/list/).

BTW: most routers and a lot of smart TVs use Linux, too. (so becoming infamous might not be the only reason ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other operating systems like Windows, Gnu/Linux, there are no executable files (.exe) so it is impossible that you run a virus without your consent.

You need to explicitly indicate to run a script.

If a virus was able to run, could not infect anything since there are no executable files.

In Gnu/Linux, processes, create codes called Daemons.

That is, if you had an FTP server, you would have a daemon listening on port 21 and upon receipt of a connection, the demon would create a process that would manage and continue listening for more connections.

The only user who has access to the demons, SU superuser (root). Only root has permission to drive the demons.

If a virus penetrated your system as a normal user would do so could not attack the daemon. In the event that the virus affected the process created by the daemon, this, would be active until the end of the process and during its execution, and could not infect anything or produce any effect.

Also, if anyone would look into ways of infecting the system, weaken or open a hole in your security, before a user of the alarm to the community in a very short time the patch as an update on all PCs it would have world as GNU / Linux is not just an OS, it is also the community's behind.

Answer (score 0):

Millions (billions?) of people use Windows -> **BIG** target for bad guys

Nowhere near as many people use Ubuntu (and those that do are generally tech savvy & not good "victims") -> *tiny tiny* target for bad guys

Comment: A bit late to the scene, but nowadays Linux is in fact market leader when it comes to installed base: the mobile market is dominated by Android (based on Linux) and servers & supercomputers are dominated by Linux. It's just the desktops that still need to upgrade to Linux.
Pardon my biased comment, I just love Linux.